# Python crashing when i try plot a graph

Tags: python, plot

Wondering if anyone can help me.

Whenever i try to run plot on python, i get an error dialogue box pop up from windows saying

"runtime error this application has requested to terminate in an unusual way"

and then another windows box saying "pythonw.exe has stopped working" and then asks if you want to try and find a solution, or close the program.

Any idea how to fix it?`

Comment: Not without seeing the code that causes the problem.

Comment: Fixed it. i think. just had to redownload C++ packages from microsoft.

Comment: Probably just delete this question, then.